# Writing interfaces in java

Tags: java

how do i approach this question>?

Write an interface named XYInterface that contains two int constants,
X = 5 and Y = 10 and a method called useXY which receives no
parameters and returns an integer value. (You don’t need to implement
the XYInterfac)

```
    public interface XYInterface {
int x = 5;
int y = 10

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface XYInterface {

    final int x = 5;
    final int y = 10;

    static public int useXY() {
        return 10; //some integer
    }

}
```

and you can call useXY from any main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        System.out.println(XYInterface.useXY());
    }

}
```